# "SystemError: <class 'int'> returned a result with an error set" in Python

Tags: python, scipy, runtime-error

I wanted to apply a very simple function using `ndimage.generic_filter()` from `scipy`. This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage

data = np.random.rand(400,128)
dimx = int(np.sqrt(np.size(data,0)))
dimy = dimx    
coord = np.random.randint(np.size(data,0), size=(dimx,dimy))

def test_func(values):
    idx_center = int(values[4])
    weight_center = data[idx_center]
    weights_around = data[values]
    differences = weights_around - weight_center
    distances = np.linalg.norm(differences, axis=1)
    return np.max(distances)

results = ndimage.generic_filter(coord,
                                 test_func,
                                 footprint = np.ones((3,3)))
```

When I execute it though, the following error shows up:

```
SystemError: <class 'int'> returned a result with an error set
```

when trying to coerce `values[4]` to an `int`. If I run the function `test_func()` without using `ndimage.generic_filter()` for a random array `values`, the function works alright.

Why is this error occurring? Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by `idx_center = int(values[4])`? When you pass `coord` to `test_func`, `values[4]` is an nparray, so you can't convert it into *an* `int`, and `int(coord[4])` returns an error: `only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`.

Comment: I suspect this is a SciPy bug; `values` will be an array of floating point values, so the line `weights_around = data[values]` should generate an `IndexError`.  Apparently something breaks the error handling in `ndimage.generic_filter`.  Could you create a new issue for this over at https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*For your case:*

This must be a bug in either Python or SciPy.  Please file a bug at https://bugs.python.org and/or https://www.scipy.org/bug-report.html.  Include the version numbers of Python and NumPy/SciPy, the full code that you have here, and the entire traceback.

(Also, if you can find a way to trigger this bug that doesn't require the use of randomness, they will likely appreciate it.  But if you can't find such a method, then please do file it as-is.)

*In general:*

"[R]eturned a result with an error set" is something that can only be done at the C level. 
 In general, the Python/C API expects most C functions to do one of two things:

1. Set an exception using one of [these functions](https://docs.python.org/3.7/c-api/exceptions.html) and return `NULL` (corresponds to throwing an exception).
2. Don't set an exception and return a "real" value, usually a `PyObject*` (corresponds to returning a value, including [returning `None`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/c-api/none.html)).

These two cases are normally incorrect:

3. Set an exception (or fail to clear one that already exists), but then return some value other than `NULL`.
4. Don't set an exception, but then return `NULL`.

Python is raising a `SystemError` because the implementation of `int`, in the Python standard library, tried to do (3), possibly as a result of SciPy doing it first.  This is always wrong, so there must be a bug in either Python or the SciPy code that it called into.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a very similar experience with Python 3.8.1 and SciPy 1.4.1 on Linux.  A workaround was to introduce `np.floor` so that:

`centre = int(window.size / 2)` becomes `centre = int(np.floor(window.size/2))`

which seems to have resolved the issue.