# Django: Letting user download PDF file from database

Tags: python, django, file, blob

How can I allow users to download PDF files from database? The PDF file is stored as a longblob in the MySQL database.

What I have so far:

views.py:

`reports = Report.objects.all()`

However doing so throws the following expcetion: `<method 'fetch_row' of '_mysql_connector.MySQL' objects> returned a result with an error set`

models.py:

```
class Report(models.Model):
    studentid = models.IntegerField(db_column='studentId')  # Field name made lowercase.
    studentname = models.TextField(db_column='studentName')  # Field name made lowercase.
    year = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    term = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    report = models.TextField() #PDF should get stored here.
```

What can I do to allow user to see the files to download? I've been looking for ways to solve this problem however can't quite seem to figure it out. Any help is appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["SystemError: <class 'int'> returned a result with an error set" in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53796264/systemerror-class-int-returned-a-result-with-an-error-set-in-python)

Comment: @luis.parravicini I don't think so. But I may be missing something. Thank you nonetheless.

Comment: @Jay_jen Save it as a base64 via FileField?

Comment: @Egor.L I deleted my comment because I misunderstood the FileField. You appear to be attempting to save a file into the database. This can have effects that sacrifice efficiency as well as slow down dev time. As a rule of thumb, Use databases for data, and filesystems for files (There are obviously exceptions to this). I can't offer insight on this error, but im willing to bet that if you use filefield and serve it as a static file, you will solve your issue, and potentially have a better implementation. read more about filefield here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/